# what is the problem of "null" values in mysql or other dbs?

Tags: mysql, innodb

As far as I know, null can be indexed in InnoDB. But many colleagues say the null values are bad DB designs. So I don't know what is the problem of "null", is the 3rd value (eq, not eq, not known) problem or something else that stops people use nullable columns?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the colleagues who are making the claim.

Comment: Null can be problematic. For example, NULL does not equal NULL, so I wouldn't be surprised if it gave wonky results when indexed.

Comment: I don't understand why vote down the question. 3rd value problem can be solved with is/is not null. But aside from the value judgment, I don't see any problems with the null value.

Comment: @makiXIE There is no problem with `NULL` values/columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` is an essential piece of SQL. It indicates a value that does not exist.

Avoiding `NULL` would lead into situations where you make up arbitary special values for items that does not exist (0, -1, empty strings etc). That would be bad design.

Comment: I agree. I am just confused about why many job interviewers ask the problems of nulls in MySQL.

Comment: Some (older) databases did not index NULL values. Most likely the question were related to this. Nowadays this is no longer a problem. MySQL does use indexes for NULLs.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, at least not when it is phrased like that. While it is true that NULL values have their place and it does not make any sense to avoid them everywhere, there are many cases where it is beneficial to avoid NULL values. There are situations where doing so can lead to more compatibility of your software (different NULL behaviour in different databases), reducing complexity of algorithms. It very much depends on the use case. Calling it bad design in general is a baseless claim in my eyes.

Comment: NULL values have a specific meaning in SQL. Avoiding NULL values *categorically* is bad design. It does not mean that you always have to use them though (Oracle indexing for example).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that 80% of columns *should* be declared `NOT NULL`.

But there are many cases where `NULL` is the 'natural' thing to use --

- A start_time is known but the end_time is *not yet* known.
- An optional attribute
- etc.

As for indexing, read the rules, and be ready to abide by them.  `PRIMARY KEY` disallows `NULLs`, but `UNIQUE` allows them.  But are they treated as "equal" or not.

As already mentioned, `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` work as expected, but `= NULL` does not.  Note also `<=>`.

`LEFT JOIN` creates artificial `NULLs` (when the 'right' table's row is missing).  An example of that usage:

```
   FROM a
   LEFT JOIN b ON ...
   WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

See `COALESCE()` for a way to turn `NULL` into something else.  Example:

```
SELECT ...,
       ( SELECT name FROM foo WHERE ... ) AS foo_name,
       ...,
     FROM ...
```

may deliver `NULL`.  This would be friendlier:

```
SELECT ...,
       COALESCE(( SELECT name FROM foo WHERE ... ), 'N/A') AS foo_name,
       ...,
     FROM ...
```

Personally, I often shun `NULL` in these two places:

```
    string VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('') -- empty string is usually good enough
    choice ENUM('unknown', 'this', 'that') NOT NULL  -- easier to display and test
```

There is virtually no performance difference (space or speed) between `NULL` and `NOT NULL`.